# automount usb disk after pluged

Tags: linux, usb, mount, fstab

from the man page of **fstab**

```
auto - file system will mount automatically at boot, or when the command 'mount -a' is issued.
noauto - the filesystem is mounted only when you tell it to.
```

However, what I want is that **usb storage device is not mounted on boot but auto mount once plugged in**. Apparently make **auto** enabled will not automount if usb device is plugged after the system boot. Instead, one has to use **#mount -a** as root or **$ mount blah blah** as normal user to make it mounted, with the condiction that **auto,nofail,user** is enabled.

currently the fstab is like this:

```
 # two entries for 340 G mobile hard disk
UUID="333c9d2f-1c2a-482e-83f7-616fa45a478a" /mnt/MobiC ext4 noauto,rw,users,exec,nofail 0 0
UUID="D0CC0864CC0846E6"   /mnt/MobiD  ntfs-3g defaults,noauto,users,nofail 0 0
```

and my system

```
uname -a
Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

with I3wm. I normally browse files based on command line.

more comments: I have tried 
[fstab on boot: mount when device is plugged in](https://superuser.com/questions/449922/fstab-on-boot-mount-when-device-is-plugged-in)
and it does not work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most distributions achieve that feature with a set of clever udev rules and possibly a helper program. Have a look at the udev manual and those rules.